# After installing my VSTO add-in through a Wix Installer when I open outlook it asks to be installed again

Tags: visual-studio, wix, installation, vsto, outlook-addin

I have created an outlook add-in with visual studio and I have also created an installer project with wix. When I run the installer it installs perfectly fine but the only problem is that when you then open outlook it asks if you want to install the add-in again but this time with ClickOnce. Is there a way to stop this?

I have tried going to the properties of the VSTO project and turning off 'Sign the ClickOnce manifests' but this just gets checked back on when I build and the problem just continues.

Comment: I have already developed dozon of outlook VSTO addins and Wixtoolset. I think you have issue in load behaviour. Let me know if you need in wix toolset

Comment: @Shyam Thanks for the reply. I seemed to have fixed the issue by manually adding a key to \Software\Microsoft\VSTO\Security\Inclusion. Though I imagine this is not suggested. I think a better solution I just discovered would of been to add file:/// infront of the manifest path to avoid the ClickOnce prompt. 

Another issue I have found though which you might be able to help me with is how do I force the install keys to not go into the WOW6432Node for x64 OS and x64 Outlook installs

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you mixed ClickOnce and VSTO manifests. Basically, iyou deployed a ClickOnce manifest instead of VSTO one.

The [Deploy an Office solution by using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2019) article describes the required steps to create a Windows Installer for your Office solution.